# Error When Input Leads With A Zero Or Decimal Point

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a unit converter written in Visual Basic with Visual Studio 2013. The program works fine until the user starts a calculation with a zero or a decimal point. Then I get this error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in      Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "." to type 'Decimal' is not valid.
```

Here is some of my program code.

```
Private Function GetLength1(ByVal decLengthUnit1 As Decimal) As Decimal

    Dim decResult1 As Decimal

    If cboUnitType.SelectedItem = "Length" Then

        ' converts kilometer to...
        If cbo1.SelectedItem = "Kilometer" Then
            If  cbo2.SelectedItem = "Meter" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 1000)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Centimeter" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 100000)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Millimeter" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 1000000)
            End If
        End If

    Return decResult1.ToString("N").Trim("0")
End Function

Private Sub txtUnit1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUnit1.TextChanged

    If suppressTextBox1TextChanged = False Then

        ' convert string to numeric data type
        Decimal.TryParse(txtUnit1.Text, decUnit1)

        ' handle String.Empty, or negative sign
        If txtUnit1.Text = "" OrElse txtUnit1.Text = "-" Then
            txtUnit2.Text = ""

        ElseIf cboUnitType.SelectedItem = "Length" Then
            suppressTextBox2TextChanged = True
            txtUnit2.Text = GetLength1(decUnit1)
            suppressTextBox2TextChanged = False
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stack trace would help pinpoint the line on which the error occurs.

However, from what I can see, the error is on the last line of your GetLength1 function.  You are returning a string, but the function is declared as returning a Decimal.

Therefore if your result is zero, then the following line:

```
Return decResult1.ToString("N").Trim("0")
```

will trim the zero, leaving an empty string, which can't be converted to Decimal (your function's return type).

I suggest you change the return type of `GetLength1` to String:

```
Private Function GetLength1(ByVal decLengthUnit1 As Decimal) As String
```

Comment: I have changed the return type to String as you suggested and it solves the issue of a zero and decimal point as input. What now would you suggest for the format of the end result? What would you use for the ToString(?) method? Which number format would be best? I only want the decimal point to show if the result has something past it. I would also like the option of maybe later making it accurate to 9 precision points. Thanks for your input thus far.

Comment: I would also like to know more about the "stack trace" you mentioned in the first line of your post. Perhaps, keep it separate from your response to my first comment, if you would.

Comment: @Zack - "I would also like to know more about the "stack trace" - if you put a Try/Catch around your code, you can inspect the thrown exception, which will include a stack trace.  Or for an unhandled exception, look in Event Viewer

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in the code posted.  `GetLength1` is incomplete and has a missing ELSE or END IF.  Second, this is not entirely correct:

```
If txtUnit1.Text = "" OrElse txtUnit1.Text = "-" Then
     txtUnit2.Text = ""

ElseIf cboUnitType.SelectedItem = "Length" Then
    ...
End If
```

These are not mutually exclusive at first glance, so both special situations it is meant to handle may not always be addressed.  They would probably be better off as independent `Ifs`.

Next, `Decimal.TryParse(txtUnit1.Text, decUnit1)` returns a T/F value indicating if the conversion was possible, but you dont evaluate it.  Since the decimal result (`decunit1`) will be sent to a math routine, it would make sense to perhaps abort the rest of the procedure if it is not a valid value.

The main problem is in your `GetLength1` function.  It is declared as Decimal, but you are anticipating how you will use it *elsewhere* and trying to convert to string on the return.  Turn on Option Explicit and these types of errors will be flagged.  Leave GetLength as a proper decimal to avoid converting it back to a number somewhere and convert to string when and where it is displayed.

```
Private Function GetLength1(ByVal decLengthUnit1 As Decimal) As Decimal
...
   Return decResult1 
End Function
```

to use it:

```
 txtUnit2.Text = GetLength1(decUnit1).ToString
```

The error msg and where it is tells you everything: converting the number `.01` to a string for the return, prevents VB from implicitly casting it to Decimal for the return in some cases.  you were trying to convert/cast a decimal to a string back to a decimal.